# One cardview having extra size

Tags: android, imageview, android-cardview

As you can see, one cardview is having extra size. All other cardviews are of same size. I think this is happening due to **android:adjustViewBounds="true"**. How to make all cards of same size. I'm passing a list of objects to the adapter. The adapter is getting passed to recycler view. Here is the screenshot [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView_faq"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView_icon"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:text="ImageViewIcon" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:paddingTop="24sp"
                    android:paddingBottom="16sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:text="tv_title"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_sub_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="16sp"
                    android:text="tv_text_other_lang"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This isn't the solution, just an observation, but the outer most LinearLayout is pointless since it contains only one element, and CardView is effectively a FrameLayout.  Well, other than the margins but there are more efficient ways to include that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use static height with different dimens for different screen resolutions.

Comment: But that's an alternative, what's the solution?

Comment: why you using weightSum? fill_parent deprecated .Solution:change height like this for example 120dp (use dimen xml files)

Comment: changing to match_parent is also giving same result

Answer (score 0):

Put height that you want not wrap_content in LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="150dp"> <android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/cardView_faq" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"> <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="start" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal"> <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgView_icon" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:paddingLeft="16dp" android:paddingStart="16dp" android:paddingTop="16dp" android:paddingBottom="16dp" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:scaleType="centerCrop" android:text="ImageViewIcon" /> <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="start" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="2"> // adjust to have better space for your textview. <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_title" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="start" android:paddingTop="24sp" android:paddingBottom="16sp" android:paddingLeft="16dp" android:paddingRight="16dp" android:text="tv_title" android:textSize="24sp" /> <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_sub_title" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="start" android:paddingLeft="16dp" android:paddingRight="16dp" android:paddingBottom="16sp" android:text="tv_text_other_lang" android:textSize="14sp" /> </LinearLayout> </LinearLayout> </android.support.v7.widget.CardView> </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the parent of card view from linear layout to relative layout solved the issue